# Set membership for all elements of A in B

Tags: python, set

Let's say I have two sets:

```
>>> a={'a','b','c','d'}
>>> b={'a','d'}
```

Is there a standard operator that tells me if all elements of `b` are contained in `a`? Currently I am doing it via:

```
>>> b==a&b
True
```

Comment: `b.issubset(a)` or `b <= a`. Or use `b < a` to test for proper subset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

```
a={'a','b','c','d'}
b={'a','d'}
b.issubset(a)
# True
```